What do people call such a chart with a strip of activity types per time?
What do people call a chart like that below which has days on Y axis and time of the day on X axis while color represents a kind of activity (data gathering, processing, etc.)?

It is very close to heatmap discussed in the What do people call a chart with a strip of peak values in time intervals?, but this one represents not the levels of value, but just a type.
If I want to ask on forums how to implement one with the specific tool what is the best way to name it additionally to the image and description?
Note
I believe a good answer from Nick Cox on the aforementioned question applies here, so I would recommend it to the interested reader.

It looks a bit like a Gantt chart.

@mdewey, no Gannt chart has activities on Y axis and just "binary" filling for them in the chart area. So, when you read Gannt chart you see the sequence of activities which could repeat on X axis and usually don't on X axis (although can). Here on Y axis you have days and this gives you a way to explore periodicity, stability in time (in days) and trends like "more imitation time by the end of the week". On real charts weeks could be blended up to see summaries, which I avoided to show here to be far enough from heatmaps.

This is not quite a duplicate but much of the discussion in the linked post is highly relevant here too. Gantt fits this chart even better than that in the linked thread.

@NickCox, as I know the Gantt chart it is used to plan some work where the work items (WBS) are listed on the Y axis and mostly (!) we don't use colors for the bars (except, may be, critical path, planned/done work, etc.); at least classical Gantt chart doesn't use colored bars. Anyway (1) on the Y axis there are items, not days; (2) bars linked with predecessors; etc. It looks similar, but when I hear "Gantt chart" I assume project planning, not data like this. So, I agree that this is a bar chart, but I am in twenty minds about Gantt chart here.

@NickCox, to be more precise, if I say somebody showing this picture "This is my Gantt chart", they will think I am incompetent in project planning and will start to explain me how Gantt chart really works and what it consist of (WBS, dependencies, early and late dates, etc.); that's what I mean here when I say "this is not exactly Gantt chart".

It's called a "Stacked Bar Chart".  The vertical version is a "Stacked Column Chart."  https://www.exceldemy.com/make-a-stacked-bar-chart-in-excel/, and the same naming in LibreOffice.  In your case, since the "days" add to the same total, it looks like a "Percent Stacked Bar Chart", even though it isn't.

@jbowman, thank you for the hint. At the same time I would say "it could be implemented with/by stacked bar chart", although as you correctly noticed, it requires the totals to sum up to the constant value. With this I mean that it could have its own name/type. Anyway, thank you, it helped.

Sorry, my stance is simply that this is more like a Gantt chart than the graph discussed in your concurrent thread. I was showing some agreement with @mdewey. Whether Gantt charts can be coloured (surely they can) and whether they only apply to project planning (a more serious detail) are other questions. Stacked bar chart is common in my reading and works well too.

You can always make up your own name. Every name starts somewhere with a single suggestion.

@NickCox, absolutely. I asked just to avoid reinventing the wheel and avoid situation when people answer "before asking how to implement, read the book on basics and learn what is it called, maybe you won't need to implement if you can name and search correctly; with a proper name you will find it ready to use in your toolset".

@NickCox indeed, I did not say it was a Gantt chart. I said it looked a bit like a Gantt chart.

@jbowman It's not simply a stacked bar chart - the ordering or position of bars in a bar chart has no meaning whatsoever. Here, the bars indicate not only the duration of the activity, but also when it occurred. A stacked bar chart could only tell you that 4 hours of data gathering occurred on Monday, but this chart additionally tells you that it occurred from midnight - 4am. Those aren't cumulative durations on the x-axis, they are times of day - we could not reorder the bars and represent the same data (as you can with a bar chart).

@Nuclear Hoagie the ordering or position of bars in a bar chart has no meaning whatsoever  I have seen many examples where it does, because the variable in question, whether outcome or predictor, has intrinsic order.

@NickCox Ordering the bars according to the natural order of an ordinal variable may make the chart easier to read, but doesn't change what it represents. In the chart shown here, moving the bars around makes the chart mean something entirely different (e.g. data gathering done from 12pm-4am Monday vs. done at any other time). In contrast, the position of ordinal bars usually doesn't matter - a chart showing some value by age group would have a natural order to put the bars, but the interpretation would be exactly the same no matter what order the bars were in.

I still consider no meaning whatsoever to be unclear and unhelpful. If you want to emphasize that a jumbled bar chart contains just the same information as an ordered bar chart, you're right, but only in the sense that "helpful not that's" is intelligible as a shuffling of "that's not helpful".
